# How to hide these blue marks which I think is from version control?

Tags: xcode, xcode10

See image below, not sure if I did something or it's something new in Xcode 10. How to disable/hide it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Preferences > Source Control > General` and uncheck the checkbox

[image]